# Docker image for Windows

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

Has any one tried building a docker image for Windows (7.1/8)? The closest answer available for me is from ScottGu's Blog. See here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/docker-and-microsoft-integrating-docker-with-windows-server-and-microsoft-azure

But I was wondering, is there any one else tried to build the same?

Comment: for any one looking for quick reference, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft released (Windows Server 2016 Technical Preview 3) today with container support which can be downloaded at:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-technical-preview

Other Interesting Links:
[Preparing Windows Server Technical Preview for Windows Server Containers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/container_setup)

[Quick Start: Windows Server Containers and Docker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker)

[Quick Start: Windows Server Containers and PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_powershell)

[Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Docker](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4)

Comment: Broken links :( was really looking forward for this info

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server

Answer (score 11):

Currently, Windows does not support containerization like the Linux kernel does. The announcement from Scott Gu that you linked to details that Docker has partnered with Microsoft and the Microsoft will be building in containerization technology into the next version of Windows. However, for now, there is no way to create a native Windows container and you will have to use tools like [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) to achieve containerization on Windows (although boot2docker is a virtual machine running Linux on Windows)

Comment: Is wirdows container available now officially from Microsoft?

Comment: @RaviKanasagra I don't know if they've included it in the Windows 10 beta build, but I doubt it and I don't know anything about if they are doing Windows Server beta build. But supposedly by mid 2015 you should get native Windows containers (http://www.zdnet.com/article/docker-container-support-coming-to-microsofts-next-windows-server-release/)

Comment: @RaviKanasagra In the meantime, try Spoon (https://spoon.net/)

Comment: Boot2Docker is deprecated in favor or docker machine, and Microsoft has announced containers for MS Server 2016 (nano they are calling i guess)

Answer (score 2):

WinDocks just released a port of the Docker engine for Windows 8, Windows 10, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2016.   We may look into supporting Windows Server 2008 . . . and would have Windows 7 at the same time.

There is a free downloadable version available at [WinDocks](http://www.windocks.com/community-docker-windows)

*Disclosure: I am the Co-Founder of WinDocks*

Comment: Their site certificate expired in June 2016 - are they still around?

Comment: Sorry for being slow in responding, but yes, WinDocks is still around and doing well!   In fact, we just released support for a new empty container for support of Java, Nginx, Node.js and other container ready executables.